# How to make an imported image transparent in Power BI?

Tags: image, powerbi, dax

I'm trying to create a Power BI report where the user is displayed an image based on what they select in the report's table.

For example, if I select the Toyota row in the below image, then I should be presented with a picture of a Toyota. If I select the Honda row, then I should be presented with a picture of a Honda.

[image: Toyota]

[image: Honda]

I'm trying to use imported (embedded) images to accomplish this (Insert > Image), since having hosted or Base64 encoded images have their own set of challenges in my circumstance. The problem is that I haven't been able to find a way to make imported images transparent. Since these images are on top of each other in the report, I will need to make one or the other transparent based on the table selection. For other shapes, or for the images' backgrounds, I can use conditional formatting and a DAX measure such as the following to accomplish this.

```
Toyota Background = IF(SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[model]) = "Toyota", "#FFFFFF", "#FFFFFF00")
```

There is no such conditional formatting ability for the image shape as a whole, though. Does anyone know how one could accomplish this? It doesn't have to be that an image is specifically made transparent as long as it accomplishes my goal above. I would be open to using custom visuals, but I would like to avoid a hosted or Base64 encoded image solution if possible.

**Note for future readers:** If you are able to use hosted or Base64 encoded images, then the [Image Pro by CloudScope](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/wa104381297?tab=overview) custom visual can be used to accomplish the goal above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of **June 2022**, this does not appear to be possible and I have not found any proposals on [Power BI Ideas](https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/).

As mentioned towards the end of the question above, if you are able to use hosted or Base64 encoded images, then the [Image Pro by CloudScope](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/wa104381297?tab=overview) custom visual can be used to accomplish this.